# Replace all files of a certain type in all directories and subdirectories?

Tags: file, bash, replace, find

I have played around with the find command and anything else I can think of but nothing will work.

I would like my bash script to be able to find all of a file type in a given directory and all of its subdirectories and replace the file with another.

EX: lets say
/home/test1/randomfolder/index.html

/home/test1/randomfolder/stuff.html

/home/different/stuff/index.html

/home/different/stuff/another.html

Each of those .html files need to be found when the program is given /home/ as a directory to search in, and then replaced by echoing the other file into them.

Is this possible in bash?

Comment: Have you considered using `unionfs`? It's *designed* for overlaying directory trees like this.

Comment: What other file is? Would the command work like `my_file_replace /home/ index.html /tmp/new_index.html` and copy `new_index.html` over the found files? Is it certain file name instead of certain file type?

Comment: Of course you can do it, you didn't try hard... what have you actually tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should more or less get you going in the right direction:

```
for file in `find . -type f -name \*.html`; do echo "new content" > $file; done
```

Comment: That is literally exactly what ive been looking to do for.... 2 days now. Thank you sir.

Comment: Ahhh, just one more question, I have the user entering the extension of the file theyre replacing the .html file with. Is there anyway to change the extension of the files if they are not already the same. 
I have $extn=".html" and $deextn= whatever they input(being the extn of the file theyre replacing the html file with) 

so its finding .html files but were replacing them with .php files is there a way to replace the content and the extension to .php?

Thanks